# Android - Reading data from tabs / fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I'm working on an Android app that does nothing more then storing data in a SQLite database and displaying it.

Since I have a .NET background I started off developing the app with MonoDroid (C#). After developing the app with MonoDroid I thought it would be fun to redevelop it with Java and learn along the way.

In the original app I used a TabActivity and created 4 tabs to stucturize the data I want to save in a single table. Underneath the tabs I placed a button. A click on the button collects all data on the 4 tabs to store it, and it worked perfect.

Now developing with Java I noticed that the TabActivity is deprecated and I found out that I have to use fragments. I was able to create the tabs following this [article](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/). However, I am no longer able to read the data on the tabs. I searched online and tried the most ridiculous "solutions" for a couple days in a row now, and I start to doubt if the functionality I look for is possible.

Please advise me what to do! Is it possible to recreate this functionality using fragments? If so, can anyone give me some pointers?
If not, what would be the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should improve your question by providing more details about the problem: What kind of data do you get from the tabs? How does your current fragment based code looks...

Comment: It's definitely possible, and there's many ways of doing it, but it's hard to tell why it's not working for you without some code, or at least a few examples of what you've tried.